# Reload of page after rebuild is very slow

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, angular-cli

I recently went from CSS to SCSS instead.

Suddenly afterward my project is very slow for loading the page after a rebuild. (30-50 seconds)

I literally did nothing else than add SCSS instead of CSS. Just changed the files and changed the settings in .angular-cli to use SCSS instead.

Let me know if I can share some more to help to troubleshoot.

I have no idea why this is the case.

Terminal:

```
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: 528351f97868ee9f6cc1                                                         
Time: 1857ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 178 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 46.1 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 26.6 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.2 MB [initial]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: b4d9b9ae09285a8f41b1                                                         
Time: 350ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 178 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 44.9 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 26.6 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.2 MB [initial]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: 3da1ef8d97c8d4dafca1                                                         
Time: 323ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 178 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 44.8 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 26.6 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.2 MB [initial]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

[image: Network description]

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with angular-cli and webpack: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1980

Comment: I've had a look at the link. It seems like most of the have a problem with a long rebuild process, where mine is at a long reload, of the newly rebuiled, page.

Comment: Also this was mentioned - maybe this link is more specific: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2656 - as mentioned the source map generation is pretty slow (also like shown in your example output)

Comment: Could it be related to the rebuild causing your browser to empty it's cache? Or perhaps your server to empty it's cache?

Comment: Maybe you could introducte chuncks in your webpack configuration, and that I think will speed up development because not your whole code base will be re-processed after making changes.